# How can you create a stroke that covers half of the shape?

Tags: vector, stroke, figma

Im somewhat new to figma so forgive me if this is a basic question. What is the best way to create a partial outline? For example,

[image]

I initially duplicated the rectangle and made it a bit bigger, but the proportions for the curve were no longer correct.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

It's a little tricky, but possible.

1. Draw a square and round the corners, set a fill, but no stroke.
2. Duplicate it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, then add a stroke and remove the fill. Set the stroke to "center".
3. Using the Move Tool <kbd>V</kbd>, double click on the stroke to edit it, and add nodes. Note: This is a tricky part, since you have to add a centre node first, then you can add others to the left or right of the centre node.
4. Select some segments and <kbd>Delete</kbd> them. Note: It can be quite difficult to select a segment. You need to hover your mouse over a segment between two nodes, the line changes colour slightly to show when you've selected it.
5. Select the filled square, and bring it to the front using <kbd>]</kbd>

[image]